# what is the best way to write a combo box in django?

Tags: python, html, django

I try making a combo box in django. I only found doing it with HTML. Is there a form based django code to do it?
For example I want a combo box with cities that I can select and then choose and hit submit to send the city to another page.
thanks

Comment: Have a look at the form docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/widgets/#selectmultiple it might be just what you need

Answer (score 12):

If you have a static list of cities, you can create a combobox using `ChoiceField`:

```
from django import forms

class SelectCityForm(forms.Form):
    CITY_1 = 'city_1'
    CITY_2 = 'city_2'
    CITY_CHOICES = (
        (CITY_1, u"City 1"),
        (CITY_2, u"City 2")
    )
    cities = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CITY_CHOICES)
```

IF you are saving cities into the database, you can use `ModelChoiceField`:

```
class SelectCityForm(forms.Form):
    cities = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=City.objects.all())
```

Comment: Why do you put a dot at the end of `CITY_CHOICES` item tuple?

Comment: @SergeKishiko Fixed. It was a typo. Thanks!

Comment: Amazing stuff ! Thank a lots !

Comment: Why do you need the `CITY_1` and `CITY_2` constants? It works fine without them, here.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a list of cities, you can use create a `form` like this:

```
class myForm(forms.Form):
    city_list = ['city1','city2']
    city = forms.ChoiceField(choices=city_list)
```

But, if your cities goes from your model you can use use this:

```
class myForm(forms.Form):
    city = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=City.objects.all())
```